# Why does WinINET change from using Kerberos to NTLM when responding to an auth demand when using Windows Authentication?

Tags: iis, kerberos, ntlm, loadrunner, wininet

We are currently loadtesting a Sharepoint environment hosted in IIS8.5 (On Windows 2012R2), using Loadrunner 11.52. We are using the WinINET based replay mechanism as there were SSL issues when trying to use the LR sockets implementation.

The authentication for the site is set to allow Windows Authentication. The users are all unique Active Directory users.

We have an issue where after starting 50 users, the users start failing due to them being unable to authenticate.

We have captured both successful (first 50 users) authentication and unsuccessful (users after the first 50) auth using Fiddler.

On initially loading the web page, the server returns a 401 with authentication headers as expected:

Request:

```
GET https://myserver/Pages/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Cookie: WSS_FullScreenMode=false
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Host: myserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
SPRequestGuid: ad71f69c-0b10-d049-46c6-1f0b1f7bd574
request-id: ad71f69c-0b10-d049-46c6-1f0b1f7bd574
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 2
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4667
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:13:44 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

WinINET then handles this appropriately, returning a Kerberos auth token, which the server accepts:

```
GET https://myserver/Pages/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Cookie: WSS_FullScreenMode=false
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Host: myserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Negotiate YIISMQYGKwYBBQUCoIISJTCCEiGgMDAuB...<long-auth-token-string>...=
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 07:13:44 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:13:44 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: ad71f69c-db17-d049-46c6-15c51828a26e
request-id: ad71f69c-db17-d049-46c6-15c51828a26e
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 40
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYGzMIGwoAMKAQChCw...<long auth token>...=
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4667
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:13:44 GMT
Content-Length: 80492


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><
...
```

Some googling has suggested that the "YIIS" at the beginning of the auth token indicates that it has chosen Kerberos in response to the `Negotiate` auth option. This works fine for the first 50 users we start (each with unique AD user credentials).

However, for the 51st user, and each subsequent user, WinINET seems to start attempting to use NTLM authentication instead, which the server rejects. 
Request  (same as previously successful user):

```
GET https://myserver/Pages/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Cookie: WSS_FullScreenMode=false
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Host: myserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response (same as previously successful user):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
SPRequestGuid: 6a71f69c-6b4f-d049-46c6-1e90257415f1
request-id: 6a71f69c-6b4f-d049-46c6-1e90257415f1
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 1
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4667
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:09:10 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

Client then sends the request for auth:

```
GET https://myserver/Pages/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Cookie: WSS_FullScreenMode=false
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Host: myserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAA...<short NTLM auth token>...==
```

Some googling suggests that the T1R at the start of the auth token means it has chosen to use NTLM this time, instead of Kerberos which was used for all the users up till this one.

The server responds with another 401 to this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAACAAIADgAAAAVgonicMgf76hzy7QAAAAAAAAAAL4AvgBAAA...<long NTLM auth token>=
SPRequestGuid: 6a71f69c-cb6b-d049-46c6-14cbc16d1ea9
request-id: 6a71f69c-cb6b-d049-46c6-14cbc16d1ea9
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 1
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4667
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:09:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Wininet then sends another auth request as follows:

```
GET https://myserver/Pages/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Cookie: WSS_FullScreenMode=false
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Host: myserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAKIAAACEAYQBu...<much longer NTLM token>...=
```

Which results in another 401:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
SPRequestGuid: 6a71f69c-cb6b-d049-46c6-18ce53703ae9
request-id: 6a71f69c-cb6b-d049-46c6-18ce53703ae9
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 236
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4667
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:09:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

At this point WinINET seems to give up, and passes the 401 on to LoadRunner which then fails the user.

The first 50 users keep working as normal. We can also load another user manually through IE while those 50 are still running. We can also wait some time and eventually we can start more users.

So, there seems to be two issues here:

1. Why is WinINET changing to use NTLM auth instead of Kerberos after 50 users have been started?
2. Why is the server rejecting the NTLM auth.

Any ideas on what might be causing this, and/or how I can investigate further, would be very appreciated. My suspicion is that it may be some sort of Active Directory limit that blocks Kerberos from working for a period after 50 users have been authenticated, however I do not know how to prove/disprove that.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago, but could it be an issue with your AD server? Perhaps WinINET is having trouble contacting AD to get a Kerberos ticket, so it fails back to NTLM. 

Did you ever resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes it was similar to that - there was some limit (the AD team never explained what exactly) that was indeed causing Kerberos to fail. NTLM auth wasn't allowed to the requests just failed with 401s